# Split and join element in 2D array

Tags: python

I am newbie in python. I have split a list which contains 100 separate string. It all have 300 chars in it. After splitting, it became to act like 2D array and I want to join them together to get an list in the beginning.

Below is my sample list and what I have tried but it does not work. I want to replace ' ' instead of '1' and remove less than 3 length of chars and join them together. Only replacing function does not work, I cannot remove words this situation.

```
1        c1|FaAO120O'8ovfoy1W#atvGs1[1s1[1/1]O-a8o1-...
2        O8v^10O#to1'#^'^tv1^]s111t01Otaq>-ata_1...
3        *#^-G1_#O-#b^'ta8a2%e1|28Oot^12#O-#ys1>c...
```

```
def tokenize(text): 
    return text.split("1")

def trimm(text):
    return ' '.join([i for i in data if len(i) > 3])

token_data = [tokenize(i) for i in X]
#trim_data = [trimm(i) for i in token_data]
for n in token_data:
    for i in token_data[n]:
        res=trimm(i)
```

Below is after tokenize function.

```
['c', '|FaAO', "20O'8o\x02vfoy", 'W#at\x1bvGs', '[', 's', '[', '/', ']O-a8o', '-\x1b-\x03\x1b#', '^]', '-a\x02\x1b', 'av', 'vc]]\x1b#a\x02d', ']#^-', 'O', 'v\x1bz\x1b#\x1b', "A\x1b'#\x1bvva^\x02", '\x03#^cd0t', '^\x02s', '[', '\x03o', "-\x1b\x02^'Ocv\x1b", 'Ov', 'W\x1b88', 'Ov', 'O', '-\x1b\x02tO8', '\x03#\x1bOf', 'A^W\x02\x08', '', '>0\x1b', 'av', '\x03\x1ba\x02d', 't#\x1bOt\x1bA', 'Wat0s', '[', 'gO8oA^8', 'Wat0', 'v^-\x1b', 'vc__\x1bvv', '\x03ct', 't0\x1b', 't#\x1bOt-\x1b\x02tv', '\x03\x1ba\x02d', "'#^zaA\x1bA", 't0#^cd0', '0\x1b#s', '[', "'vo_0aOt#avt", 'O#\x1b', '\x02^t', 'vOtav]O_t^#o\x08', '', '>^-']
```

Below is after trimm function

```
|FaAO 20O'8ovfoy W#atvGs ]O-a8o --# -a vc]]#ad ]#^- vz# A'#vva^ #^cd0t -^'Ocv W88 -tO8 #Of A^W ad t#OtA Wat0s gO8oA^8 Wat0 v^- vc__vv t#Ot-tv ad '#^zaAA t0#^cd0 0#s 'vo_0aOt#avt vOtav]O_t^#
```

I can do above situation only one 300 chars string. However I want it to do all strings in the original list. Therefore how can I make a loop that trimm and join every string ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you have a question?  This is a question and answer site.  You need to ask a specific question about programming.  Please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited my post again.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines look wrong:

```
for n in token_data:
    for i in token_data[n]:
```

`n` will be an element of `token_data`, taking `token_data[n]` does not make sense to me, since `n` is not an index, instead I would use for `i in n:` for the second `for` loop.